# handsontable bug: when launched inside jquery ui dialog boxes are unedittable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, handsontable

I have some pretty simply jQuery that runs inside a dialog jquery ui popup box

```
$.ajax({  
      url: 'json.php?supplier_id=' + supplier_id, 
      dataType: 'json', 
      type: 'GET', 
      success: function(res){ 
        $("#hot").handsontable({ 
          data: res.data, 
          minSpareRows: 1, 
          startCols: 1, 
          minRows: 1, 
          minCols: 3, 
          columns: [ 
            {data: 1}, 
            {data: 2}, 
            {data: 3} 
          ], 
          colWidths: [160, 495, 60], 
          rowHeaders: false, 
          colHeaders: false, 
          contextMenu: false 
        }); 
      } 
    });
```

the above code runs in the "complete" callback of the jquery ui dialog and visually works fine, however I cannot change anything! When I try to edit the cells I can only "delete" the information in the grid fields, one character at a time, I cannot edit it positively only negatively, it's almost as if my entire keyboard is key press disabled. Has anyone ever seen this bug before and know a way around it?

Comment: Do you get any errors? It's probably crashing out and you're not seeing it. Most likely because you're setting the data object to res.data and the `res` object (which HOT tries to access when you change data) gets lost after the success function ends

Comment: No, there are no errors in console.log - it accepts no keydown event other than accepting the delete key and nothing else, everything else works as intended, including setting the fields readOnly, mouse dragging multiple drag boxes.. I think it has to be a render bug

Comment: mmm it could be. Hard to debug from this side. Could you provide a fiddle? For the ajax call, just call any random site that won't crash, we don't care about that anyways.

Comment: here is a video of the issue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EynFvm9D9y4

Comment: it is too complex for a fiddle: I have replicated the bug here - you can view the source http://hands.cbtservices.net/

Comment: it appears to be a jquery version issue "upgrading" (aka breaking :-/ 200 other things) the code appears to fix it http://hands.cbtservices.net/test.php (which works) illustrates this

Comment: Awesome, why don't you post your own answer and declare it the correct one so that others with this issue know to upgrade jquery.

Comment: The simplest fix for me is `modal:false`, I think the jquery overlay is causing this issue for modal dialog box

Answer (score 0):

According to the Asker:

"It appears to be a jquery version issue "upgrading" (aka breaking :-/ 200 other things) the code appears to [fix it](http://hands.cbtservices.net/test.php) (which works) illustrates this."

So turned out to be a jQuery updating issue.